# Can I somehow (with match types?) introduce a default type to use if a type is undefined/abstract?

Tags: scala, scala-3, match-types

Let's have some application specific type:

```
  class Carrier
```

I am dealing with polymorphic tuples of its subtypes. Occasionally, a `Carrier` would have a payload (it is use-case specific, rather than dictated by a `Carrier` subclass) and I'd like to collect those in a new tuple:

```
  class Carrier {
    type Payload[T <: Tuple] <: Tuple
  }
```

Then, my data would look something like this:

```
  (fullCarier.asInstanceOf[Carrier { type Payload[T <: Tuple] = Cargo *: T }], emptyCarrier.asInstanceOf[Carrier { type Payload[T <: Tuple] = T }])
```

The problem here is that 'full' carriers are a very corner case, with 95% of use cases at least dealing only with 'empty' ones. Having `(SubCarrier1 { type Payload[T <: Tuple] = T }, SubCarrier2 { type Payload[T <: Tuple] = T })` instead of `(SubCarrier1, SubCarrier2)` gets extremely noisy very quickly - I'd rather drop that 'payload' use case completely than resort to this. Even

```
  type Empty[C <: Carrier] = C { type Payload[T <: Tuple] = T }
  val data :(Empty[SubCarrier1], Empty[SubCarrier2])
```

is too high a price to pay. I'm still new to Scala 3, but perhaps this could be defined
somehow as a default case of a match type? Pseudo code:

```
   class Carrier { type Payload[T <: Tuple] <: Tuple; type Full :Boolean with Singleton }

   type Collect[D <: Tuple] = D match 
     case h *: t => (h match 
       case Carrier { type Full = true; type Payload[P] = payload[P] } => payload[Collect[T]]
       case Any => Collect[t]
     )
     case EmptyTuple => ()
```

For that, I would essentially need something like this:

```
  val carrier :CarrierSubclass1
  type MyType[X] = carrier.Payload[X] match {
     case payload[X] => payload[X] //carrier.Payload is a concrete type
     case _ => X //if CarrierSubclass1 does not define Payload, I want to use a default.
  }
```

This is somewhat fishy, as the result of matching would depend on our knowledge about the type of `carrier`: if it is in fact a `CarrierSubclass2 <: CarrierSubclass1` and `CarrierSubclass2` *has* a definition of `Payload`, then the result would be different even though we match the same object. It is however not that different to invariant higher types, where `MyOtherType[CarrierSubclass1]` is unrelated to `MyOtherType[CarrierSubclass2]`.
To tell the truth, I am still confused as to how match types work.

A bigger problem of course is that `D` could be `SubCarrier1 *: Tuple`, and I still would like to be able to do something sensible with it. I don't like how Scala 3 handles tuples, as for a type like above, the full type of the tuple has to be known for all defined operations like `Concat`, etc., to be available. On the other hand, defining those recursively as member types inside `Tuple` would work and not lose any type information, even if the executed code is generic (i.e., `D =:= (H *: T)`). So, the result of `t1.concat(tuple2)` would be of type `t2.AppendTo[T1]`, where `t :T1`, and anyone knowing the exact type of `T2` and `T1` would have full information, despite it being not known where the concatenation took place.

So, realistically, I am probably looking into dealing with my own `HList`-like type,

```scala
  trait HList { 
    type Payload 
    def payload :Payload
  }
  case class ::[H <: Carrier, T <: HList](h :H, t :T) extends HList {
    type Payload = h.Payload[t.Payload]
    def payload = h.payload(t.payload)
  }
  case object HNil extends HList {
    type Payload = EmptyTuple
    def payload = EmptyTuple
  }
```

but somehow tack on a match type instead of `h.Payload`.

Could something like this work?

Comment: I'm finding this problem description quite confusing. I'm still not sure what the problem is. I'm seeing bunch of "solution" proposals, but it's unclear at what point the problem (whatever it might be) could be considered "solved". Something like "dealing with polymorphic tuples of its subtypes" or "be able to do something sensible with it" is way too vague. Maybe you could also try elaborating why `class Carrier {
    type Payload[T <: Tuple] <: Tuple = T
  }` would be insufficient for dealing with the "empty" "carriers" (whatever those are - I'm still unsure).

Comment: I thought the question title is clear enough. I'd like something that behaves like a match type `type MyType`, which matches a type member `carrier.Member` of some object `carrier :CarrierSubclass1`, and if the former is defined by `CarrierSubclass1` as `type Member = X` (or `carrier` is of a refined `CarrierSubclass1 { type Member = X }`, then `MyType` also becomes `X`. However, if `carrier.Member` is undefined (but the type of `carrier` is some concrete type `CarrierSubclass1`, not an abstract type), then it uses some default type.